translating yt-dlp command to python didnt worked
I have a small problem converting a console command into python code.
cmd: yt-dlp --referer https://referer.link --no-part "https://video.link"

This works fine in the terminal. i tried to convert it to python like this:
import yt_dlp

ydl_opts = {
    'referer': 'https://referer.link',
    'no_part': True,
}

video_url = 'https://video.link'

with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([video_url])

this executes with following error:

ERROR: [generic] Unable to download webpage: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001FC91E32D80>: Failed to resolve 'link' ([Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed) (caused by TransportError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001FC91E32D80>: Failed to resolve 'link' ([Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed)"))

does anyone know whats wrong with my code?
thank you
Already tried serval yt_opt

the referer  part is mandatory?

You could use the http_headers opts.
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

opts = {
    'http_headers': {
        'Referer': 'https://referer.link'
    }
}
video_url = 'https://video.link'
with YoutubeDL(opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download([video_url])

